# How to pass a parameter as part of SAML attributes from a SP

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, pingfederate

We are currently creating a SSO using Ping Federate for a 3rd party application say App3 .
It is an Idp initaited SSO set up and the SP's for both our application and the App3 is already in place.
The requirement is to open this App3 in a new browser window whenever we click on a link in our own application . The problem is that we need to pass a paramater say user's license number to App3 and they are asking it to be sent as part of SAML attributes . 
My question is that is it possible to do this from our end  , or do we need to send this value as part of URL parameter to Ping Federate and then Ping Federate will need to add this value to SAML response that is being sent to APP3.
Please Advise.

Thanks

Comment: You can send it as a SAML attribute and then pull it out the request.

Comment: this plugin is really useful - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/saml-message-decoder/mpabchoaimgbdbbjjieoaeiibojelbhm?hl=en

Comment: Can you please explain in detail how can I add the saml attribute in the URL ? Thanks.

Comment: If its not sensitive data (http://example.com/foo?bar) - bar being licence number, but if you have control at the other side send it as a SAML attribute and intercept the request and pull it out.

Comment: If I were trying to do something like this, I would make App3 do SP-init, then when you click on the link in your app, pass the license to app3 in the redirect as a query parameter. The SP redirects the user for authn at the IdP, and you're all set. Passing a parameter back to the IdP during IdP-init is possible, but you'll need to use OGNL to pull it out of the request.context object.